# How can I populate a drop down list with web pages in a folder in my web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a drop down that displays all the available we pages with in a specific folder in my web app.  So basically I have an Admin page and there I want to have a drop down that displays the web pages in a folder named "Clients".  This drop down needs to be updated automatically when a new web page is created within that folder.

This is all I have so far in my code:

```
 <br />
   <b>Select Web Page:</b>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="Web_Pages" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="WebPage_SelectedIndexChanged">
   </asp:DropDownList><br />
 <br />
```

And Code Behind:

```
  protected void WebPage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Not sure what to do here to display the pages??
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the file listing and add them to your dropdown:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("/");
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.aspx")
    .Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x));
Web_Pages.Items.AddRange(files);
```

And this code is actually should go to `Page_Load` not `SelectedIndexChanged`.

Comment: Thanks,  however I get the following error:  `Non-invocable member 'Directory' cannot be used like a method`

Comment: you should add `using System.IO;` to your page

Comment: Brilliant,  Thanks! It displays everything now, but is it possible to display only the .aspx page and not the .aspx.cs and ,aspx.designer.cs as well as the web.config files.  Sort of like filtering it?

Comment: Your welcome. have a look at my edited answer, `GetFiles()` accepts a pattern.